# Detecting two (almost) vertical lines, and find the gap between them in (pxl)

Tags: image-processing, image

I have no knowledge in mathematica, python, and other great softwares.

I saw the following picture in a website;

[image]

Where a software detects objects (like bus) and tells about its height or width or such things.

---

Well, I work in a chemical laboratory. Cameras are used to take pictures of the samples to be analyzed.

See a real picture:

[image]

---

Then I need to measure the distance (the black gap). What I always do is to open the image using Paint in my Personal Computer, select the range manually, and take the reading. See the illustration of what I do:

[image]

$549$ in this particular example, (I do not need the height like the $185$) (only width is required).

---

My question now, can mathematica, or any other software, detects those two red vertical lines (which are not in the original image, I put them for illustration purpose) and measure the distance between them in (px)?

---

Some Other examples:

1. Small gap:
   [image]
2. Not a very clear gap. However, the required distance is the one in the middle (not in the left) white/grey-to-white/gray (by averaging) (Errors are accepted up to +/- 5 px). 
   [image]

---

If you need me to clarify something, please let me know. I am sorry I do not know English very well. That is the reason.

---

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

**Update 2:** A simpler/faster approach to get the gap length:

```
ClearAll[hWidth]

hWidth = Composition[Max, Cases[p : {0 ..} :> Length[p]], 
   Drop[#, #[[-1, 1]] - 1] &, Drop[#, 1 - #[[1, 1]]] &, 
   Split, Map[Max], Transpose, ImageData, MorphologicalBinarize, ImageCrop];

hWidth /@ {img1, img2, img3}
```

> ```
>  {548, 17, 61}
> ```

or

```
ClearAll[hWidth2]

hWidth2 = Composition[# - 1 &, Max, Differences, 
   SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"] &, 
   Map[Max], Transpose, ImageData, MorphologicalBinarize, ImageCrop];

hWidth2 /@ {img1, img2, img3}
```

> ```
>  {548, 17, 61}
> ```

**Original answer:**

A three-step procedure:

1. Full vertical dilation of the input image using [`Dilation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dilation.html)
2. Selecting components (all rectangles after dilation) using
   [`SelectComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectComponents.html)
   and
3. Using [`ComponentMeasurements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html) to get the `"BoundingBox"` and
   `"CaliperWidth"` of the selected components

```
ClearAll[vDilate, internalRectangles, dataSet]

vDilate = ColorNegate @ 
   Dilation[MorphologicalBinarize@#, ConstantArray[1, {ImageDimensions[#][[1]], 1}]] &;

internalRectangles[w_: 1] := Rectangle @@@ Values[
    ComponentMeasurements[
      SelectComponents[vDilate @ #, 
       #CaliperWidth > w && #AdjacentBorders == {Bottom, Top} &], 
     "BoundingBox"]] &;

dataSet[w_:1] := ComponentMeasurements[
   SelectComponents[vDilate @ #,
     #CaliperWidth > w && #AdjacentBorders == {Bottom, Top} &], 
  {"BoundingBox", "CaliperWidth"}, "Dataset"] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
{img1, img2, img3} = Import /@ 
  {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRjAA.jpg", 
   "https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ALv.jpg", 
   "https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Zcd.jpg"}
```

[image]

For the first two images we get a single rectangle using the default value (`1`) for the caliper width threshold:

```
dataSet[] @ img1
```

[image]

```
HighlightImage[#, internalRectangles[]@#] & @ img1
```

[image]

```
dataSet[] @ img2
```

[image]

```
HighlightImage[#, internalRectangles[] @ #] & @ img2
```

[image]

For `img3`, we get many rectangles with the default caliper width threshold:

```
dataSet[] @ img3
```

[image]

```
HighlightImage[#, internalRectangles[]@#] & @ img3
```

[image]

Using a larger value for the threshold caliper width gives a single rectangle:

```
dataSet[25] @ img3
```

[image]

```
HighlightImage[#, internalRectangles[25]@#] & @ img3
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can select the rectangle with maximal width from `internalRectangles[]@img3`:

```
HighlightImage[#, 
   MaximalBy[#[[2, 1]] - #[[1, 1]] &]@(internalRectangles[]@#)] &@img3
```

> same picture

**Update:** To get the internal rectangle with maximum width in a single step, we can define `dataSet` as follows:

```
ClearAll[dataSet2]
dataSet2 = MaximalBy[#CaliperWidth &] @
    ComponentMeasurements[
     SelectComponents[vDilate @ #,  #AdjacentBorders == {Bottom, Top} &], 
    { "BoundingBox", "CaliperWidth"}, "Dataset"] &;

dataSet2 /@ {img1, img2, img3}
```

[image]

Comment: Overly extended answer with far too many updates, for the sake of clarity, please post only what you think is the correct answer.

Comment: It seems easy for some command writers. Dear, as I said: "I have no knowledge in mathematica, python, and other great softwares." Well, where should I paste the code you provided? Possible in mathematica online? or I must download it? Can I use that code for around $10,000$ pictures, .. Please dear, I need you to consider my knowledge. What I need is a very simple procedure that I should do,like;(Download the software from "LINK". Open the "Window".Paste the provided code. Drag your pictures, click "Run".  Provide some screenshot if possible my dear.That would be really really appreciated.(+1)

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari, you can use the code with  Mathematica Online.  Go to the page wolframcloud.com and  follow the instructions to open an account.  Then copy/paste/evaluate the code in this post in a new notebook.

Comment: @kglr Well, See this pic https://ibb.co/N7nN0m9 , am I doing right, pasting it in the right place? If right, what should I change now, like #AdjacentBorders and #CaliperWidth and "BoundingBox" and such things,, need to be changed? Ok, then where to upload the pictures to be processed. Please help me sir, your support is really appreciated.

Comment: @kglr Check this plz https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX69N.png

Comment: Hussain, copy/paste/execute the rest of the code blocks: `{img1, img2, img3} = Import/@...`  then `dataSet[] @ img1` ,  and then `HighlightImage[#, internalRectangles[]@#] & @ img1`  etc...

Comment: @kglr Sorry for disturbance sir, my knowledge is my problem. The way did: img1 is ok, img2 is also ok, BUT I changed img3, by changing the link to https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VRyG.jpg .  The picture was imported successfully, but the result was $-\infty$. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL2vn.png

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari, you need to pre-process `img4 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VRyG.jpg"]` to adjust the  contrast and brightness of the image   before using the functions `hWidth` , `dataSet`, `internalRectangles`.  For example you can use  `img4b = ImageAdjust[img4, {.6, .8}]` for adjustment so that the piece on the right is detected.

Comment: @kglr I think (NOT SURE), I can continue now. Words are powerless to thank you, bounty after $7$ hours :).

Comment: @kglr https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223901/1-combining-codes-2-editing-them-3-evaluating-the-outputs

Comment: @kglr please dear see flinty suggestions, I believe you can help . Thanks https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223926/mathematica-12-1-trial-version-very-slow-to-evaluate-a-property-in-multiple-pic

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari,  try the updated/ faster version of `hWidth`.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari will you award to kglr as you said? The bounty will expire soon. Or is there still more work needed?

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps a less precise but very fast approach which returns reasonably good widths for these three images. It binarizes the images, and collapses all rows down onto a single row by adding them together and unitizing them. It then looks for runs of zeros in the middle of the row and returns the lengths. I take the `Max` of these lengths after I call the function on each image:

```
gapSizes[img_] := 
 Module[{values, splits, 
   bimg = Binarize[MinFilter[img, 4], Method -> "Mean"], dsc},
  (* remove small blobs with < 1% of the total pixel count *)
  dsc = Round[0.01*Times @@ ImageDimensions[img]];
  bimg = DeleteSmallComponents[bimg, dsc];
  values = Unitize[Total[ImageData[bimg]]];
  If[values[[1]] == 0, values = Drop[values, First@FirstPosition[values, 1] - 1]];
  splits = Select[Split[values], #[[1]] == 0 &];
  Length /@ If[splits[[-1, 1]] == 0, Most[splits], splits]]


imgs = Import /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRjAA.jpg", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ALv.jpg", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Zcd.jpg", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9M7d.jpg"};
Max[gapSizes[#]] & /@ imgs

(* returns {552, 15, 51, 140} *)
```

Note it is quite sensitive and images with low brightness areas will perform badly.

Comment: It worked much much much faster than the previous code, also with reasonably good widths. Thanks a lot. BUT, for some images, like https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9M7d.jpg, it shows $173$ (NOT reasonably good width). See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icrlx.png Almost $137-139$, not $173$. Can we improve this? THANKS A LOT!

Comment: I am still trying but could not know why for some images it shows (not) good width. It work fast and good for some images, that is really great job from you. I believe you can.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Some of your images have poor brightness on the leading edge of the right hand side. I don't think a one-size-fits-all solution exists without at least some manual cleanup of the images.