# Mathematica 12.1 trial version, very slow to evaluate a property in multiple pictures

Tags: image-processing

I am a new mathematica user.

I am using the following code to measure the internal rectangle width in some images. When I run mathematica for $1$ image, it takes a short time. Also, it works and it shows the results for more than one image. However, it takes (EXTREMELY) long time to show the results, especially when the number of picture more than $5$. It took around $25$ minutes to process around $35$ pictures!

One possibility, that my requirement from mathematica is too much, and it is normal to process $35$image/$25$min.

One possibility, that I use mathematica in a wrong way to get the result; I go to `Evaluation` bar then `Evaluate Notebook` option.

[image]

One possibility, that the code can be modified in a way it will work faster.

One possibility, that this version of mathematica (12.1) has an issue.

PLEASE CHECK THE FOLLOWING:

```
ClearAll[vDilate, internalRectangles, dataSet]

vDilate = 
  ColorNegate@
    Dilation[MorphologicalBinarize@#, 
     ConstantArray[1, {ImageDimensions[#][[1]], 1}]] &;

internalRectangles[w_ : 1] := 
  Rectangle @@@ 
    Values[ComponentMeasurements[
      SelectComponents[
       vDilate@#, #CaliperWidth > 
          w && #AdjacentBorders == {Bottom, Top} &], "BoundingBox"]] &;

dataSet[w_ : 1] := 
  ComponentMeasurements[
    SelectComponents[
     vDilate@#, #CaliperWidth > 
        w && #AdjacentBorders == {Bottom, Top} &], {"BoundingBox", 
     "CaliperWidth"}, "Dataset"] &;

{img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6} = 
 Import /@ {"D:\\SHARGAM\\167716 6 SDGM Comp 2 HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) \
(61-65 C) 2 4046 08-03-12  10-06-2020.jpg", 
   "D:\\SHARGAM\\252929 6 SDGM Comp 2 HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (75-80 \
C) 2 4048 09-16-57  11-06-2020.jpg", 
   "D:\\SHARGAM\\232614 6 SDGM Comp 2 HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (70-75 \
C) 2 4051 03-15-54  11-06-2020.jpg", 
   "D:\\SHARGAM\\211778 6 SDGM Comp 2 HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (70-75 \
C) 2 4051 21-05-53  10-06-2020.jpg", 
   "D:\\SHARGAM\\192633 6 SDGM Comp 2 HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (70-75 \
C) 2 4052 15-25-53  10-06-2020.jpg", 
   "D:\\SHARGAM\\172707 6 SDGM Comp 2 HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (65-70 \
C) 2 4050 09-31-56  10-06-2020.jpg"}


ClearAll[dataSet2]
dataSet2 = 
  MaximalBy[#CaliperWidth &]@
    ComponentMeasurements[
     SelectComponents[
      vDilate@#, #AdjacentBorders == {Bottom, Top} &], {"BoundingBox",
       "CaliperWidth"}, "Dataset"] &;

dataSet2 /@ {img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6}
```

Where;

"D:\SHARGAM\167716 6 SDGM Comp 2 HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (61-65 C) 2 \
4046 08-03-12  10-06-2020.jpg", "D:\SHARGAM\252929 6 SDGM Comp 2 \
HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (75-80 C) 2 4048 09-16-57  11-06-2020.jpg", \
"D:\SHARGAM\232614 6 SDGM Comp 2 HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (70-75 C) 2 \
4051 03-15-54  11-06-2020.jpg", "D:\SHARGAM\211778 6 SDGM Comp 2 \
HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (70-75 C) 2 4051 21-05-53  10-06-2020.jpg", \
"D:\SHARGAM\192633 6 SDGM Comp 2 HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (70-75 C) 2 \
4052 15-25-53  10-06-2020.jpg", "D:\SHARGAM\172707 6 SDGM Comp 2 \
HRDH B2 4200 rpm + TB) (65-70 C) 2 4050 09-31-56  10-06-2020.jpg"

are the path of the images to be processed, they look like this;

[image]

It took around $3.5-4$ minutes for those $6$ images!

---

If I need to find the `caliperwidth` of $1000$ images, it may take $1000$ life-times!

---

You can see my [previous problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223732/detecting-two-almost-vertical-lines-and-find-the-gap-between-them-in-pxl), kglr helped a lot. Many thanks to kglr.

---

**AGAIN, I am a new mathematica user. (2 days).**

---

Any help/suggestion to modify the code, or correcting me on how to evaluate the outputs, would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Getting `dataSet2` is the slow bit. Through profiling on a fresh kernel `MaximalBy[#CaliperWidth &]@
   ComponentMeasurements[
    SelectComponents[
     vDilate@#, #AdjacentBorders == {Bottom, Top} &], {"BoundingBox", 
     "CaliperWidth"}, "Dataset"] &;` is where most of your time's going. You could reduce the image resolution with `ImageResize[img,512]` if you're prepared to sacrifice some precision in the measurements.

Comment: Also you could evaluate `dataSet2 /@ {img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6}` in parallel if you have multiple cores with `ParallelMap[dataSet2, {img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6}]` but I don't know if the trial version will allow you to use the `Parallel...` functions.

Comment: @flinty Should I delete dataSet2? or Should I just add `ImageResize[img1,512]` , `ImageResize[img2,512]` , `ImageResize[img3,512]` , ... , `ImageResize[img1000,512]`? Because without deleting dataSet2, it took time too. Please dear, can you edit it and paste it as an answer?

Comment: Where you `Import` the images, just change `Import` to `ImageResize[Import[#],512]&`

Comment: @flinty please dear, is it possible for you to copy the code from the post, edit it, and paste it as an answer? I am poor in mathematica because I am new. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried your code with the image in your question and for that it took about 8 sec. on my 1 year old Window 10 laptop. A second try only take about 2 sec., I think that is either due to caching effects or because `ComponentMeasurements` has some initialization overhead. I think it would make sense to understand why a single picture takes about 40 seconds for you and only 2 sec. for me. Is the resolution of those pictures higher than the one in your question? Have you checked whether the runtimes for each of the pictures is roughly the same?